# How the gl_TessCoord is computed during the tessellation?

Tags: opengl, glsl, jogl

Currently I am learning the tessellation shader of OpenGL. But when it comes to the built in variable "gl_TessCoord" in the tessellation evaluation shader, I can't understand how it is calculated.

I know that the "gl_TessCoord" is different when different tessellation mode is used (quads or triangles). And I checked both the blue book and red book, yet they only give a rough explanation telling that it represents the weight in terms of the input vertices. Any ideas?

Here is the sample code of tessellation of a rectangle:

```
#version 430 core
layout ( quads) in;
void main( void)
{
    // Interpolate along bottom edge using x component of the
    // tessellation coordinate
    vec4 p1 = mix(gl_in[0].gl_Position, gl_in[1].gl_Position, gl_TessCoord.x);
    // Interpolate along top edge using x component of the
    // tessellation coordinate
    vec4 p2 = mix(gl_in[2].gl_Position, gl_in[3].gl_Position, gl_TessCoord.x);
    // Now interpolate those two results using the y component
    // of tessellation coordinate
    gl_Position = mix(p1, p2, gl_TessCoord.y);
}
```

Here is the sample code of tessellation of a triangle:

```
#version 430 core
layout ( triangles) in;
void main( void)
{
    gl_Position = (gl_TessCoord.x * gl_in[0].gl_Position) +
    (gl_TessCoord.y * gl_in[1].gl_Position) +
    (gl_TessCoord.z * gl_in[2].gl_Position);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gl_TessCoord` represents the same concept with all primitive topologies.

This vector is the position within the current primitive, and it is probably best not to think of it as `x`, `y` and `z`. Since it is relative to a surface, `u`, `v` and `w` (optional) are more intuitive. You can call the coordinates whatever you want (e.g. `xyz`, `rgb`, `stp` or `uvw`) , mind you, but `uvw` is the canonical notation.

> #### [OpenGL 4.5 (Core Profile)](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf#page=414) - *11.2.2 Tessellation Primitive Generation* - p. 392
>
> > Each vertex produced by the primitive generator has an associated
> >     (u, v, w) or (u, v) position in a normalized parameter space, with parameter values in the range [0, 1], as illustrated in figure 11.1.
> >
> > For triangles, the vertex position is a barycentric coordinate (u, v, w), where u + v + w = 1, and indicates the relative influence of the three vertices of the triangle on the position of the vertex.
> >
> > For quads and isolines, the position is a (u, v) coordinate indicating the relative horizontal and vertical position of the vertex relative to the subdivided rectangle

In the case of quads, each component measures the distance from *two* edges of a unit square. In the case of triangles, it is the distance from the *three* edges of a triangle (barycentric coordinates). This is why your example tessellation shader for quads uses only `u` and `v`, while the triangle example uses `u`, `v` and `w`.

#### To better illustrate this, consider the following diagram:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So does it mean that those lines with different colors can be considered as axis forming a coordinate system, where the (u, v, w) or (u, v) are determined?

Comment: @a_shuang: Yes, they're each one axis in a coordinate system relative to the primitive. They're not really related to the x,y,z axes as you think of them in Cartesian space, so that's why u,v,w is used. In the triangle, even though those three axes look a lot like a 3D Cartesian space, they all exist in a single plane (the triangle) and are all relative to an individual edge of the triangle. This coordinate space ranges from [**0.0**,**1.0**].

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman There's an easy way to connect the barycentric coordinates to cartesian coordinates:  Think of the abstract triangle as literally having vertices at (1,0,0), (0,1,0), & (0,0,1) in both coordinate systems.  In this way (u,v,w) is the same as (x,y,z).